# What is the maximum friends name I can get through Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to get my all facebook friends name, using the below code I can get maximum 1036 numbers of friends name, where as in my facebook profile I have 1091 friends name.

```
$requestFriends = $fb->get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name&limit=100'); 
        $friends = $requestFriends->getGraphEdge();
// if have more friends than 100 as we defined the limit above on line no. 68
        if ($fb->next($friends)) {
        $allFriends = array();
        $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
        $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
        while ($friends = $fb->next($friends)) {
            $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
            $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
        }
        foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
            //echo $key['name'] . "<br>";
        }
        echo count($allFriends);
    } else {
        $allFriends = $friends->asArray();
        $totalFriends = count($allFriends);
        foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
            //echo $key['name'] . "<br>";
        }
        echo count($allFriends);
    }
```

I have changes the limit from 100, 500, 100, 2000 , but it gives 1036 maximum. Any one knows how to get all friends name please.

Comment: First of all, I hope you are aware that  this endpoint is for tagging people in Open Graph stories _only_ – it is not a “workaround” to get all of a user’s friends for any different purpose. // Users can disable all 3rd-party apps in their settings, in which case they will be completely invisible to all apps.

Comment: @CBroe, Okey, my findings is that, its not possible in the current Graph API. Thanks